# Vue 3 - Laravel - Inertia Partial reloading not working properly

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have experience with the previous router-view but right now I'm confused. The Problem I'm facing is that all components are updated, the page is not reloading, but everything is being updated.

The issue that I'm facing is when I click on for example "Home", a Transition will be added to My component and It will fade in with this sub-menu (1,2,3), but when I click on any of this sub-menu items (1,2,3) I was expecting to update only Submenu Component  and not to get transition again for both My component and Submenu Component

[image]

The structure that I have is next:

Layout :

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
  <h1>This is layout</h1>
  <nav>
    <Link :href="route('home')">Home</Link>
    <Link :href="route('info')">Info</Link>
    <Link :href="route('about')">About</Link>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <Transition name="page" appear>
      <span />
    </Transition>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

MyComponent:

```
<script setup>
import Layout from "@/layouts/Layout.vue"
</script>

<template>
  <Layout>
    <h1>This is my component</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link :href="route('my.route.1')">Menu 1</Link>
        <Link :href="route('my.route.2')">Menu 2</Link>
        <Link :href="route('my.route.3')">Menu 3</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="submenu-content">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </Layout>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

SubmenuComponent:

```
<script setup>
import Layout from "@/layouts/MyComponent.vue"
</script>

<template>
  <MyComponent>
    <h1>I'm submenu component and my content is here</h1>
  </MyComponent>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

MyController.php

```
public function viewSubComponent(Request $request) {
   $data = [1,2,3,4,5];
   return inertia('SubComponent', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use templates called "layouts" to build web pages. The advantage of layouts is that the components declared within them will not reload after a page refresh... only the content they load will change.

##### Declare Layout

```html
<!-- ./resources/js/layouts/Layout.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Header elements (ex. navigation) -->
    <h1>This is layout</h1>
    <nav>
      <Link :href="route('home')">Home</Link>
      <Link :href="route('info')">Info</Link>
      <Link :href="route('about')">About</Link>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <!-- Submenu, You need to implement the submenu in the layout if you want to avoid reloading it every time. It is not impossible, and this approach will help you achieve a consistent page layout. -->
      <slot name="submenu"></slot> <!-- it will not update, while content equal, because outside of transition -->
     
      <!-- Content -->
      <div class="submenu-content">
        <Transition name="page" appear>
          <slot></slot> <!-- it will update, when refresh page by transition -->
        </Transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

It is up to you to design it. The important thing is to place a default slot somewhere where Vue can later implement the content of the page.

#### Page (How to implement Layout?)

```html
<!-- ./resources/js/pages/HomePage.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
     <!-- Submenu -->
     <template #submenu>
       <SubMenu />
     </template>
    
     <!-- Page content -->
     <h1>I'm submenu component and my content is here</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Layout from '@/layouts/Layout.vue'
import SubMenu from '@/components/SubMenu.vue'

defineOptions({
  layout: Layout, // define Layout to Page (Vue 3 Composition API)
})
</script>
```

If you invoke the HomePage component through Inertia, its content will be placed inside the slot element of the Layout. If you navigate from there to another page, such as AboutUsPage.vue, which also specifies MyLayout as its layout, only the content within the slot will be updated, and everything outside the slot will remain unchanged.

#### Separated submenu

**IMPORTANT: it's not layout, just a component.** You can only have one layout to page.

```html
<!-- ./resources/js/components/SubMenu.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link :href="route('my.route.1')">Menu 1</Link>
        <Link :href="route('my.route.2')">Menu 2</Link>
        <Link :href="route('my.route.3')">Menu 3</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### Transition

Elements placed in a `<transition>` block refresh after the page loads, so it is necessary for the submenu...

1. to be placed in a separate transition block.
   or
2. to be placed outside the transition - like in the current example -.

##### More informations

[What is "defineOptions"?](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineoptions)

[InertiaJS Layout-Page relationship](https://inertiajs.com/pages)

[Vue Transitions](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html)

Comment: Exactly what I was missing. Thanks mate :)